# For Loop Explaination

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Good afternoon everyone. So I've got an exam in programming Java tomorrow, and I'd received a study guide to the exam that I'm rather stuck on. I've got this problem that I'd like, if possible, for someone to explain the outcome of?

```
public class FinalProb {
  public static void main(String[]junk) {
     int[] huskey = {1, 8, 5};
     int beagle = 0;
     for (int k = 0; k < huskey.length; k++) {
       beagle += huskey[ k ];
       System.out.println( beagle );
     }
  }
 }
```

Apparently, the System output will give an answer of:

1

9

14

So basically, can someone explain to me how the code up top would give the output provided? If possible, please dumb it down as much as possible, because as of right now, I have no clue how this happens. Thanks to anyone that is able to help, and I hope you all have a great night :D

Comment: Hint:  mentally replace `beagle` with `sum`.

Comment: First beagle = 1, second = 1+8; third = 1 + 8 + 5.

Comment: get a pen and paper and write the output on each iteration.

Comment: how does down voting the OP help anybody?

Comment: @CSCH I started this thing a year or so ago, that's how I learned how to properly use SO

Answer (score 1):

This is a restatement of the comments, but in a bit more detail.

Get a piece of paper and a pencil. Divide the paper into columns for "k" and "beagle", and a column for notes if you get confused.

Begin by writing the initial value of `beagle` in its column: 0.

Move on to the loop. Write the initial value of `k` in its column: 0. Check whether to do a loop iteration: Is it less than the length of the `huskey` array? It is.

Now advance to the `+=` for the first iteration. Evaluate the right hand side by looking up the value of `k` and indexing into the `huskey` array. Add to the current value of `beagle` and write it in the `beagle` column. That puts 1 in the `beagle` column.

Now move on to the `println`. It is going to print the last value you wrote in the `beagle` column, 1.

Go back to the `for`. It will increment `k` by one, so write a 1 in the `k` column. As before, check whether the current value of `k` is less than the array length...

Carry on doing this, keeping the latest value of each variable as the last entry in its column. With practice, you will be able to do this in your head, but until you can, do it on paper.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FinalProb {

  public static void main(String[]junk) { // must be separated by space
     //**************** variable initialization ******************
     int[] huskey = {1, 8, 5}; //declaration of int array
     int beagle = 0; // int declaration
     //***********************************************************
     // loop until k reaches huskey array lenght (it loops 3 times because huskey length is 3)
     for (int k = 0; k < huskey.length; k++) {
       beagle += huskey[ k ]; // add the values of huskey with given index 'k' to beagle variable
       // huskey[0] = 1
       // huskey[0] = 8
       // huskey[0] = 5
       System.out.println( beagle );
     }
  }
 }

// 0 + 1 = 1 (new beagle value in first loop)
// 1 + 8 = 9 (new beagle value in second loop)
// 8 + 5 = 14 (new beagle value in third loop)

// expected output:
// 1
// 9
// 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of k is from 0 and end at K < length.husky(This is 3):

- k = 0,   k = 1,   k = 2,

when k = 3, 3 is not < 3, therefore, the loop will end
As a result:
when people say: beagle += (something), it means beagle = beagle + (something), then the value of beagle will be change in to [beagle + (something)]. Since beagle is initialized to 0, then it keep add on the value inside of array husky[].
So:

- k = 0, beagle = 0 + husky0 = 1
     k = 1, beagle = 1 + husky1 = 9
     k = 2, beagle = 9 + husky2 = 14

Hope this helps.